# Ant is on a vertex of a triangle. What is the expected number of seconds to get back to the original vertex?

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

An Ant is on a vertex of a triangle. Each second, it moves randomly to an adjacent vertex. What is the expected number of seconds before it arrives back at the original vertex?

My solution: I dont know how to use markov chains yet, but Im guessing that could be a way to do this. I was wondering if there was an intuitive way to solve this problem. I would have guessed 3 seconds as an answer.

I'm assuming that if it is at Vertex A, there is a 1/2 chance of going to Vertex B or C. So minimum number of seconds is 2 seconds. Max number could be infinite if it keeps bouncing back between B and C without returning to A.

I'm still not sure how to do this puzzle.

Comment: You're right! The answer is: $1 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{2} ^ n \cdot n\right] = 3$

Comment: Consider the triangle as a directed graph with $3$ vertices and $6$ (directed) edges. The expected length of the ant's walk is equal to the sum, over all $6$ edges, of the expected number of times that edge is traversed. A simple argument shows that the expectation is the same for each edge. For the $2$ edges leaving the initial vertex the expectation is $\frac12,$ so the expected length is $6\cdot\frac12=3.$ This generalizes to any finite connected symmetric digraph.

Comment: Hi Andrew (@andrew.punnett), I can intuitively understand your solution more. So you are taking the probability of of every outcome. When it is at Vertex B, then it is 1 second away so we add one second. Then say it moves back to A, then EV is 1/2*1second. Now for the possibility of moving to C and then A, (1/2^2)*2, and so on.

Comment: Hi Bof (@bof), thanks for posting your solution too. However I'm not sure what a graph is? Im not a CS person, just a regular mechanical engineer. Maybe you can point me to good resources to figure this out more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ant moves $1$ time, then moves another $N$ times to return to the original vertex. After the first move, the ant either takes one more move back to the original vertex, or it moves to the other non-original vertex, then continues trying from there.   Recursively then:

$$\mathsf E(N) ~=~ \tfrac 12+\tfrac 12(1+\mathsf E(N)) \\ ~ \\ \therefore \quad \mathsf E(N)+1=3$$

The expected time the ant takes to move and return to the origin is $3$seconds.

Comment: Hi Graham, I'm not sure how you got the relation recursively? How do we do recursion? I apologize, Im a mechanical engineer and I havent learnt the CS mathematics. Is there some online resource to learn how to think like this?

Comment: Is this clearer?  $\mathsf E(N)$ is the expected number of steps to return to the origin from another vertex. If the ant takes one step there is an equal probability that it is either back at the origin, or at another vertex: where the expected number of steps to return to the origin is again $\mathsf E(N)$.  Thus $\mathsf E(N)= 1 + \tfrac 12 \mathsf E(N)$

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks for the reply. So this recursion thing is still not intuitive to me. This is what I can see - E(N) = (1/2)*1 + 1/2(1 + 1/2(1 + 1/2(1 + 1/2.......  So the question is how do we know where to add the E(N) again? If I do E(N) = 1/2 + 1/2(1 + E(N)) then E(N) = 2. But if I do E(N) = 1/2 + 1/2(1 + 1/2(1 + E(N)) then E(N) = 5/3. So the answer changes?

Comment: If $\mathsf E(N) = 1+\tfrac 12(\color{blue}{1+\tfrac 12(\color{navy}{1+\tfrac 12(1+\ldots )})})$ then $\mathsf E(N) = 1+\tfrac 12(\color{blue}{\mathsf E(N)}) = 1+\tfrac 12(\color{blue}{1+\tfrac 12(\color{navy}{\mathsf E(N)})})$

Comment: $\begin{align}\mathsf E(N) ~=~& 1+\tfrac 12\mathsf E(N) \\ = ~& 1+\tfrac 12+\tfrac 14\mathsf E(N) \\ ~=~& 1+\tfrac 12+\tfrac 14+\tfrac 18\mathsf E(N) \\~=~& \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k} \\~=~ & 2\end{align}$

Comment: Hi Graham, you are genius! So this makes more sense. So I see that E(N) converges to 2. In general, what can you recommend to me to read etc get better at this sort of stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the ant starts at vertex $A.$ We want to find the expected of value the random variable $X$ which is the number of vertex-to-vertex steps (i.e. the number of seconds) the ant takes. Now
$$X=X_{A,B}+X_{B,A}+X_{B,C}+X_{C,B}+X_{C,A}+X_{A,C}$$
where $X_{A,B}$ is the number of times the ant walks from $A$ to $B,\ $ $X_{B,A}$ the number of times it walks from $B$ to $A,\ $ $X_{B,C}$ the number of times it walks from $B$ to $C,$ and so on. By the linearity of expectation,
$$E(X)=E(X_{A,B})+E(X_{B,A})+E(X_{B,C})+E(X_{C,B})+E(X_{C,A})+E(X_{A,C}).$$
By symmetry we have
$$E(X_{A,B})=E(X_{A,C})\text{ and }E(X_{B,A})=E(X_{B,C})=E(X_{C,B})=E(X_{C,A}).$$
Also
$$X_{A,B}+X_{A,C}=1\text{ and }X_{B,A}+X_{C,A}=1$$
because the vertex leaves the vertex $A$ exactly once and enters it exactly once. It follows that
$$E(X_{A,B})=E(X_{B,A})=E(X_{B,C})=E(X_{C,B})=E(X_{C,A})=E(X_{A,C})=\frac12$$
and so
$$E(X)=6\cdot\frac12=\boxed3.$$
This is a special case of a general theorem about random walks on finite [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory). Namely, if an ant goes on a random walk on a finite connected undirected graph, which ends the first time it returns to the starting vertex, then the expected length of the walk is $\frac{2e}d,$ where $e$ is the number of edges in the graph and $d$ is the degree of the starting vertex. In your case the graph is $K_3,$ the complete graph on three vertices, so $e=3$ and $d=2.$

Comment: Hi @bof, thanks again for the enhanced graph explanation. I don't know much about graph theory and random walks. Looks like a new project for me. Interesting stuff... So 1). I thought XA,B+XA,C=2 and XB,A+XC,A=2. Since it will take 2 seconds each to complete both actions. 2). I see that the expectations should be all be equal to each other, but don't understand how they are equal to 1/2. 3). Intuitively, I would think that XB,C and XC,B could be a big number (jumping back and forth), but with very low probability - So i guess they cancel out?. These are the 3 main questions. Thanks again!

Comment: 1) Since the ant starts at $A,$ and since the walk ends the first time it returns to $A,$ the ant is only going to leave $A$ once. If the ant's first move is to $B,$ then $X_{A,B}=1$ and $X_{A,C}=0;$ in the other case, $X_{A,C}=1$ and $X_{A,B}=0.$ Either way, $$E(X_{A,B})+E(X_{A,C})=E(X_{A,B}+X_{A,C})=E(1)=1.$$ Similarly the ant will only arrive at $A$ once, on the last leg of the journey, so $X_{B,A}+X_{C,A}=1.$

Comment: 2) From $E(X_{A,B})+E(X_{A,C})=1$ and $E(X_{A,B})=E(X_{A,C})$ it follows that $E(X_{A,B})=E(X_{A,C})=\frac12.$

Comment: 3) True, $X_{B,C}$ can be arbitrarily large, while $X_{B,A}\le1.$ Nevertheless, both variables have the same expectation, This is because, every time the and is at vertex $B,$ it is equally likely to go to $A$ or to $C.$

Comment: In fact, $P(X_{B,A}=0)=P(X_{B,A}=1)=\frac12,$ while $P(X_{B,C}=0)=\frac58$ and, for $n\gt0,\ P(X_{B,C}=n)=\frac9{2^{2n+3}}.$ Of course, in writing my answer, I was trying to avoid computations.

Answer (score 0):

Let the 3 vertices be A, B, and C. Without loss of generality, assume that the ant starts at A.

Let $E_{A}$, $E_{B}$, and $E_{C}$ be the expected number of seconds to get back to vertex A when it's at A, B and C respectively.

We can write the following relation:

$$E_{A} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}E_{B} + \frac{1}{2}E_{C}$$

$$E_{B} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}(0) + \frac{1}{2}E_{C}$$

$$E_{C} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}(0) + \frac{1}{2}E_{B}$$

Solving the set of equations above, we have

$$E_{B} = 2 $$
$$E_{C} = 2 $$
$$E_{A} = 3 $$

$E_{A} = 3$ is the answer to the question